# I can't get info from the user and write it into a file in C using fprintf (SOLVED)

Tags: c

This code works when I run it in main in a separate file but it doesn't work in a larger project. In the project the code still asks for passenger info but doesn't write into the file.  Do you see any problem in the code?

```
void getPassengerInfo(){
FILE* passePtr = fopen("passengers.txt","a+");
FILE* bookPtr = fopen("bookings.txt","a+");
struct passengerData passenger1;
printf("Enter your last name: ");
scanf("%s",passenger1.lastName);
printf("Enter your first name: ");
scanf("%s",passenger1.firstName);
printf("Enter your id number: ");
scanf("%s",passenger1.idNumber);
fprintf(passePtr,"%-15s %-15s %-12s\n",passenger1.lastName,passenger1.firstName,passenger1.idNumber);
fprintf(bookPtr,"Passenger info:\n %-15s %-15s %-12s\n",passenger1.lastName,passenger1.firstName,passenger1.idNumber);
}
```

I also declared the function above as

```
void getPassengerInfo();
```

And this is the passenger struct that I'm using:

```
struct passengerData { 
   char lastName[ 15 ];
   char firstName[ 15 ];
   char idNumber[12];
}passengers[50];
```

EDIT: I closed the pointers and it worked.

```
fclose(passePtr);
fclose(bookPtr);
```

Comment: I suggest checking the return values from `fopen()`.

Comment: Thanks but I checked and it doesn't return NULL.

Comment: If you think your question has some value for others, please post an answer yourself. You will be able to mark it after some time as accepted, too. Else please delete it.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I'm new to this platform and I'm still learning the rules.